# Multiple Tangos Looking at one location - IR Conflict

Tags: google-project-tango

I am getting my first Tango in the next day or so; worked a little bit with Occipital's Structure Sensor - which is where my background in depth perceiving camera's come from.

Has anyone used multiple Tango at once (lets say 6-10), looking at the same part of a room, using depth for identification and placement of 3d character/content?  I have been told that multiple devices looking at the same part of a room will confuse each Tango as they will see the other Tango's IR dots.

Thanks for your input.
Grisly

Comment: I've tested with 2 devices... no problems yet. I am getting my hands on another - will update.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to use several Tangos, but I have however tried to use my Tango in a room where I had a Kinect 2 sensor, which caused the Tango to go bananas. It seems however like the Tango has lower intensity on its IR projector in comparison, but I would still say that it is a reasonable assumption that it will not work.

It might work under certain angles but I doubt that you will be able to find a configuration of that many cameras without any of them interfering with each other. If you would make it work however, I would be very interested to know how.

Answer (score 0):

You could lower the depth camera rate (defaults to 5/second I believe) to avoid conflicts, but that might not be desirable given what you're using the system for.

Alternatively, only enable the depth camera when placing your 3D models on surfaces, then disable said depth camera when it is not needed. This can also help conserve CPU and battery power.

Answer (score 0):

It did not work.  Occipital Structure Sensor on the other hand, did work (multiple devices in one place)!

Comment: please answer the question with some more explanation.

Comment: Check out this video where 6 Structure Sensors are being used in the same area and tracking on all devices is maintained: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yHqNSHR1Ts